# Powered Screwdriver for Computer Work

Tags: computer-building, case

Does anyone know of a small, high-speed power screwdriver with really low torque (hand tight) for use on computer chassis?

I screw in and unscrew screws on computer cases all day long and I'm getting tired of using a hand-held screwdriver.

I want something that's relatively small, uses some common batteries (AA, AAA), has higher speed than I can do by hand, with a clutch that stops tightening when the screw is about hand tight

Someone has to make this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a guide on [Maximum PC](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/maximum_pc_gets_screwed_so_you_dont_have_to_ultimate_screwdriver_review_roundup?page=0%2C0) on various screwdrivers.  If you look at page seven it mentions a couple of battery powered ones:

- Black & Decker Alkaline Powered Screwdriver ([Black & Decker](http://www.blackanddecker.com/productguide/product-details.aspx?productid=23592&toolview=2#details))
- Hitachi DB3DL 3.6 Volt Lithium Ion Cordless Screwdriver ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H2P05Q))

Answer (score 1):

I am HUGE fan of the [Coleman FlashCell](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4iT4dZnWBE&mode=related&search=) cordless screwdriver.  Charges in about 90s and will do plenty of screws before needing a recharge.  It uses a capacitor, so there's no charge wear, and the fast charging means there's no worries about leaving it around discharged.

There's one catch - it looks like it's sold out all over the place, possibly discontinued for now if it is changing brands or something.  There are some on ebay it looks like.  I'm glad I got mine when I did!

Edit:  It looks like the people behind the tech are [Demain International](http://www.demain.com.au/).  They apparently license out their tech for tool manufacturers. In the UK and perhaps elsewhere it looks like it was licensed to [GMC](http://www.gmcompany.com/index.cfm?module=products&pid=678).  This is a pretty awesome tool, I'm sure it will be back on the market soon.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself an unbranded (or ownbranded) cheap electric screw driver.

Every tool shop I have seen does these - here (in the UK) both Homebase and B&Q (the leading two DIY shops) have their own range of tools as well as many others. The cheapest ones are low torque and work fine for computers.

About 4 years ago, I managed to pick one up for £6 that uses 4x AA batteries - I have only changed them a few times and I like it - I use a powerful one here, but I keep this one in my tool kit for visits.

Your other best bet is eBay.